# header already sent error in wordpress when using header location for redirection in page.php

Tags: wordpress

I am using header location in wordpress page.php for redirection but it gives header already sent warning and not redirecting the page , I am redirecting page based on page slug

```
global $post;
$post_slug=$post->post_name;

 if($post_slug == 'about'){
    header("location:".get_site_url().'/about-us/');
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct just use it before get_header(); in your page.php